# Docker with selinux enabled - relabeling content in /usr is not allowed

Tags: docker, selinux

I have Docker on Centos7 with selinux set to enforcing on the host and Docker daemon is started with --selinux-enabled flag.

When I try to run the following command

```
docker run -it   -v /usr/local/xya/log:/usr/local/xya/log:z centos/systemd touch /usr/local/xya/log/test
```

I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error setting label on mount source '/usr/local/xya/log': relabeling content in /usr is not allowed.
```

As per some articles (http://jaormx.github.io/2018/selinux-and-docker-notes/), the 'z' flag is supposed to make /usr writable; not sure if I am missing something.

Docker version 19.03.3, build a872fc2f86
CentOS version: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804

Answer (score 7):

I recently had a similar (albeit different issue), I found Juan's [SELinux and docker notes](http://jaormx.github.io/2018/selinux-and-docker-notes/) helpful.

I'm having troubles finding the documentation that highlighted the following point, but I recall seeing it and was able to get around my issues by accepting it as truth. I will update it if/when I stumble across it again; Not everything within `/usr` or `/etc` will grant you write access in SELinux. At least not in the context of Docker.

You can access the `/etc` and `/usr` directories within SELinux context, but you cannot obtain write everywhere, so `z` and `Z` will occasionally give you unable to label issues when spinning up docker containers with volume mounts from those locations. However, if you have SELinux protected files elsewhere, e.g. in a users home directory, you'd be able to have Docker relabel those files appropriately -- that is you'd be able to write to those SELinux protected files/directories with the `z` or `Z` flags.

If you need to write within the `/usr` or `/etc` directories and obtaining the unable to relabel alert, the `--privileged` flag or [`--security-opt label:disable`](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1557893) flag should be instead of the `z` syntax. This would allow you to have write access, but you'd need to remove the `z` from your volume mount as Docker would still give you the unable to relabel statement.

note, you can also invoke `privileged` in the docker-compose.yml via `privileged: true` for a given service

Answer (score 3):

the image has no permission to edit or create new files in `usr` folder, from the [Docs](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/systemd/) you may start the container with `--privileged` parameter